# Why functions considered as first-class citizens are so important?

Tags: java, interface, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Java 8 provides a bunch of functional interfaces that we can implement using lambda expressions, which allows functions to be treated as 
[first-class citizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) (passed as arguments, returned from a method, etc...).

Example:

```
Stream.of("Hello", "World").forEach(str->System.out.println(str));
```

Why functions considered as first-class citizens are so important? Any example to demonstrate this power?

Comment: Java still treats functions pretty much the same way it did for a loooooonnnng time. E.g. the [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface has been around since java 1.2 and now that the `@FunctionalInterface` has been added not much has changed. But the fact that you can use lambda expressions and method references now to write shorter code is nice.

Comment: First-class functions allow you to treat _behavior_ as _data_.  This, in turn, allows you to more naturally _abstract over behavior_, which, in turn, enables you to write more expressive, higher-level APIs (like Streams.)  Which, in turn, leads to more expressive, more readable, less error-prone application code.

Comment: Another way to formulate (basically what @BrianGoetz said), is that first-class functions allow you to define **higher-order functions** that can nicely stack, compose and chain behaviour altogether, all this in a declarative, concise & readable manner. There are plenty of resources on the web about functional programming and its benefits. I like those kind of questions but I doubt SO will allow it as this is very broad.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to be able to pass *behavior* as a parameter. This is useful, for example, in implementing the [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Streams API is a perfect example of how passing behavior as a parameter is useful:

```
people.stream()
  .map(person::name)
  .map(name->new GraveStone(name, Rock.GRANITE)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Also it allows programmers to think in terms of functional programming instead of object-oriented programming, which is convenient for a lot of tasks, but is quite a broad thing to cover in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the second part of the question has been addressed well.  But I want to try to answer the first question.

By definition there is more that a first-class citizen function can do.  A first-class citizen function can:

1. be named by variables
2. be passed as arguments
3. be returned as the result of another function
4. participate as a member data type in a data structure (e.g., an array or list)

These are the privileges of being "first-class."

Comment: However, you can have all 4 items with good old single-method anonymous classes as well. Java 8 just makes things more concise. Lambdas don't introduce anything that couldn't be done without them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of expressiveness. You don't have to, but in many practical cases it will make your code more readable and concise. For instance, take your code:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of("Hello", "World").forEach(str->System.out.println(str));
    }
}
```

And compare it to the most concise Java 7 implementation I could come out with:

```
interface Procedure<T> {
    void call(T arg);
}

class Util {
    static <T> void forEach(Procedure<T> proc, T... elements) {
        for (T el: elements) {
            proc.call(el);
        }
    }
}

public class Foo {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Util.forEach(
            new Procedure<String>() {
                public void call(String str) { System.out.println(str); }
            },
            "Hello", "World"
        );
    }
}
```

The result is the same, the number of lines a bit less :) Also note that for supporting `Procedure` instances with different number of arguments, you would have needed an interface each or (more practical) passing all the arguments as a single `Parameters` object. A closures would have been made in a similar way, by adding some fields to the `Procedure` implementation. That's a lot of boilerplate.

In fact, things like first-class "functors" and (non-mutable) closures have been around for a long time using [anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), but they required a significant implementation effort. Lambdas just make things easier to read and write (at least, in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short program the shows (arguably) the primary differentiating factor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(10, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19);

  List<Integer> list = pickEvensViaLists(input);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) 
    System.out.println(list.get(i));

  System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
  pickEvensViaStreams(input).limit(2).forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x));
}      

private static List<Integer> pickEvensViaLists(List<Integer> input) {
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(input);
  for (Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    int curr = iter.next();
    System.out.println("processing list element " + curr);
    if (curr % 2 != 0) 
      iter.remove();
  }
  return list;
}

private static Stream<Integer> pickEvensViaStreams(List<Integer> input) {
  Stream<Integer> inputStream = input.stream();
  Stream<Integer> filtered = inputStream.filter((curr) -> { 
    System.out.println("processing stream element " + curr);
    return curr % 2 == 0; 
  });
  return filtered;
}
```

This program takes an input list and prints the first two even numbers from it. It does so twice: the first time using lists with hand-written loops, the second time using streams with lambda expressions.

There are some differences in terms of the amount of code one has to write in either approach but this is not (in my mind) the main point. The difference is in how things are evaluated:

In the list-based approach the code of `pickEvensViaLists()` iterates over the entire list. it will remove all odd values from the list and only then will return back to `main()`. The list that it returned to `main()` will therefore contain four values: `10, 12, 20, 30` and `main()` will print just the first two.

In the stream-based approach the code of `pickEvensViaStreams()` does not actually iterate over anything. It returns a stream who else can be computed off of the input stream but it did not yet compute any one of them. Only when `main()` starts iterating (via `forEach()`) will the elements of the returned stream be computed, one by one. As `main()` only cares about the first two elements only two elements of the returned stream are actually computed. In other words: with stream you get *lazy evaluation*: streams are iterated only much as needed.

To see that let's examine the output of this program:

```
--------------------------------------------
list-based filtering:
processing list element 10
processing list element 12
processing list element 13
processing list element 15
processing list element 17
processing list element 19
processing list element 20
processing list element 30
10
12
--------------------------------------------
stream-based filtering:
processing stream element 10
10
processing stream element 12
12
```

with lists the entire input was iterated over (hence the eight "processing list element" messages). With stream only two elements were actually extracted from the input resulting in only two "processing stream element" messages.